# Resize the height of the ListView Row in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I am working on an app using ListView to show some data which I get from server at Runtime.

I set the data in the list view dynamically. Below is my XML for ROW :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_lilay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_header_relay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/timeline_header_bg_480" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bride_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:text="STELLA"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/and_IV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/bride_tv"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
            android:background="@drawable/and" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/groom_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/and_IV"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
            android:text="JOSE"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/groom_tv"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:text="85 DIAS 23 HOURAS 22 MINUS Y 30 SEG"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/time_tv"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:text="para nuestro gran dia"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bar_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_bar_480" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo_IV"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/post_photo" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/heading_relay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_lilay"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_pic_IV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_pic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile_pic_IV"
        android:text="LOREM IPSUM TITLE"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/posttime_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/username_tv"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile_pic_IV"
        android:text="Jose Q. a las 2:30 pm el 24 september 2013"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons_relay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/heading_relay"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/like_lilay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/like_IV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/like" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/likes_count_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/likes_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/likes"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/comment_lilay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/comment_IV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/comment" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comment_count_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comment_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/commments"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fav_lilay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fav_IV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/favorite" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fav_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/favorites"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Just for the 1st ELEMENT I have to show the "**top_header_relay**" and the rest of the elements **I have to change the visibility to GONE**. In doing this, the height of the other Rows remains same as the 1st one which result a big Blank Space at the bottom of the Row.

Suggest me how can I resize the height of the other rows of the List at run time.

**ADAPTER CLASS:**

```
public class PostsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{

    ArrayList<String> itemList=null;

    private Activity _mContext=null;
    public LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    private Context _Context = null;
    private ArrayList<ViewHolder> listHolder=null;
    private int[] imageList = {R.drawable.calendar_icon,
            R.drawable.location_icon,R.drawable.fun_icon,
            R.drawable.notification_icon,R.drawable.invitation_icon,
            R.drawable.change_wedding,R.drawable.settings_icon,
            R.drawable.logout_icon};

    /**
     * PostsListAdapter
     * @param context
     * @param itemList
     */
    public PostsListAdapter(Activity context,ArrayList<String> itemList) {
        super();
        this._Context = context;
        this._mContext = context;
        this.itemList = itemList;

        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        listHolder = new ArrayList<PostsListAdapter.ViewHolder>();
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return itemList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        private ImageView _postImageView=null;
        private ImageView _profilePicImageView=null;
        private TextView _usernameTitleTextView=null;
        private TextView _timeTextView=null;
        private TextView _likeCountTextView=null;
        private TextView _commentsCountTitleTextView=null;

        private LinearLayout _likeLinearLayout=null;
        private LinearLayout _commentLinearLayout=null;
        private LinearLayout _favLinearLayout=null;
        private RelativeLayout _topheaderRelay=null;
        private ImageView _barViewImageView=null;
    }
    /**
     * 
     */
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_list_element, null);

            holder._postImageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo_IV);
            holder._postImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
            holder._profilePicImageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic_IV);
            holder._profilePicImageView.setOnClickListener(this);

            holder._usernameTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username_tv);
            holder._usernameTitleTextView.setClickable(false);
            holder._timeTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.posttime_tv);
            holder._timeTextView.setClickable(false);
            holder._likeCountTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.likes_count_tv);
            holder._likeCountTextView.setClickable(false);
            holder._commentsCountTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_count_tv);
            holder._commentsCountTitleTextView.setClickable(false);

            holder._likeLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.like_lilay);
            holder._likeLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
            holder._commentLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_lilay);
            holder._commentLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
            holder._favLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_lilay);
            holder._favLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(this);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();


        if(position!=0){
            holder._topheaderRelay = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.top_header_relay);
            holder._topheaderRelay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder._barViewImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bar_view);
            holder._barViewImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            holder._topheaderRelay = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.top_header_relay);
            holder._topheaderRelay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder._barViewImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bar_view);
            holder._barViewImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        listHolder.add(holder);

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.like_lilay:

            break;
        case R.id.comment_lilay:

            break;
        case R.id.fav_lilay:

            break;
        case R.id.profile_pic_IV:

            break;
        case R.id.photo_IV:

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your adapter class?

Comment: Did you try to set the LayoutParams for your relativelayout in getview method?

Answer (score 0):

When you populate the list, getview function is the best place to inflate the view and to set its layout attributes. You can hide the visibility of other rows based on the item position using setvisibility function

Comment: Read my query properly please .... My concern is to resize the height of the list row, as I am hiding on relative layout.

Comment: As I said, you can do it in the getview method. You can resize the height of the list row using layoutparams. get the existing layoutparams of the view using getlayoutparams and change the height and set it back to the view using setlayoutparams. I hpe i understood your question correctly. if not, apologies!